How to use custom coding standard in zed.dev
in my homedir i have this php-cs config file (.php-cs-fixer.php):
<?php

return (new PhpCsFixer\Config())
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR2'                                  => true,
        'array_indentation'                      => true,
        'array_syntax'                           => ['syntax' => 'short'],
        'combine_consecutive_unsets'             => true,
        'class_attributes_separation'            => ['elements' => ['method' => 'one', ]],
        'multiline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => false,
        'single_quote'                           => true,
        // ...
    ])
    ->setLineEnding("\n")

;

how can i make Zed editor use this config on save instead?

Maybe this will be helpful to you: https://www.reddit.com/r/ZedEditor/comments/1cxpb9o/how_to_run_code_file_in_zed_using_keyboard/
